# php comma and decimal format

Tags: php, mysql, numbers

I just want to ask if there is any PHP/MySQL datatype that can store a number with a comma and decimal such as 10,000.35

when the user hit the save button with this value, it should be stored in a MySQL table and the system can retrieve it also to be processed as number 10000.35

thanks for any help!

Comment: Just solve it on the presentation layer, do not change the way it is stored.

Comment: use [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) in displaying the value you fetch from database

Comment: thanks everyone for your useful responses. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a `CHAR`/`string` datatype.

Numeric values don't have formats. They only contain the numeric value. Commas are not relevant for numeric computation. Format the values on *output* using, for instance, [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format). That's the only time a comma is relevant, it does not need to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

Store the number without the comma in MySQL and just format the number in PHP when you are displaying it. It would be easier to keep the number without the comma in PHP as well if you're doing math with it - only use the comma when displaying the data!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be storing numeric values it is best to leave all the formatting out of it.

For instance, what if you need to localize the display so that 10,000.05 needs to be 10.000,05? You'd have a lot of work to do.

You should store the value in the database as `10000.05` and use `number_format($myValue,2,'.',',');` to display the value when it's time. This will allow you to change the literals to variables or constants should you ever have to localize. It will also allow you to configure how many decimal places you care to display.

Here's the PHP docs for [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to store it in your MySQL database **without** the comma, and then using PHP's [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to display it with the commas.

The MySQL datatype that does this is DECIMAL. DECIMAL gives you fixed decimal places without the precision errors inherent in float type. (ie 123.45 instead of 123.4499999999999999)

Comment: 123.45 for DECIMAL, 123.4499999999999999 for FLOAT, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options , using MySQL to format directly or Using PHP .... see below for examples

MySQL Direct Solution

```
SELECT FORMAT(number, 2) as formatNumber FROM table ;
```

PHP Solution

```
number_format($number,2,'.',',');
```

Thanks
:)